# Value of variable not changing

Tags: node.js, variables, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

So this is my code :

```
  while (n !== -1){
var meta = result[n].meta_data;
var tradeurl = meta[0].value;
var orderid = result[0].id;
var billing = result[0].billing;
var name = billing.first_name +" "+ billing.last_name;
var orderitem = result[0].line_items;
var orderitemid = orderitem[0].id;
console.log("n = " + n);
console.log("Order ID : " + orderid);
console.log("Using tradeurl : " + tradeurl);
console.log("Buyer : " + name);
console.log("Order : " + orderitemid);
n= n-1 ;
```

}

This is what I'm getting in the console :

```
Order ID : 2979
Using tradeurl : https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=452464312&token=1m7Sxxxx
Buyer : devang yadav
Order : 1643
n = 2
Order ID : 2979
Using tradeurl : https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=452464312&token=Gq27xxxx
Buyer : devang yadav
Order : 1643
n = 1
Order ID : 2979
Using tradeurl : https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=387415982&token=UVZYxxxx
Buyer : devang yadav
Order : 1643
n = 0
Order ID : 2979
Using tradeurl : https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=410734147&token=WIK-xxxx
Buyer : devang yadav
Order : 1643
```

So what I'm doing is getting the length of the array returned by the API, subtracting one from it as array starts at 0 index and then trying to change the value in `meta = result[n].meta_data;` so as to get new data. But for some reason it doesn't work, the value of n is changing, as seen in the console output but for some reason new data isn't being pulled.Also while I was posting this , I noticed that the tradeurl are updating but the others aren't. Where am I going wrong ?Any suggestions ?

Comment: You're using result[0] instead of result[n] in several lines of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you're passing `"0"` instead of `n`

```
var orderid = result[0].id;
var billing = result[0].billing;
var orderitem = result[0].line_items;
var orderitemid = orderitem[0].id;
```

replace with `n`:

```
var orderid = result[n].id;
var billing = result[n].billing;
var orderitem = result[n].line_items;
var orderitemid = orderitem[n].id;
```